# Apexcharts base value

Tags: bar-chart, axis, apexcharts

I have a problem with the Apexcharts chart, is it possible for the chart to be drawn from a specific value and not from 0? This concerns situations in which the bars start, for example, from 100 to present the dynamics.
Preferably on the Grouped bar chart

This is about the effect in the attached screenshot from the amCharts library. There it is defined as base value, any ideas?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMJDl.jpg)

I tried to use the Multi-series chart for this purpose, unfortunately the effect is not satisfactory and the chart with negative values, but this one starts always from 0...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min` attribute of `yaxis`.

from the [docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/yaxis/):

`min: Number || Function`

The lowest number to be set for the `y-axis`. The graph drawing beyond this number will be clipped off
You can also pass a function here which should return a number. The function accepts an argument which by default is the smallest value in the
`y-axis`.

`function(min) { return min }`